# VS Code API: How do I open up another desktop app?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using VS Code's API and I want Slack to open when a user clicks a button which I have already built.

The best thing that I've come up with until the moment is to simply point the button to https://app.slack.com/, but I doubt that's the best I can do.

I'm searching through the docs and thought that maybe [built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) could help me, but haven't found a useful example.

I'm also trying to do a simple `window.open()` on my TypeScript file with no sucess.

**EDIT:**

I tried `window.open("slack://open");` and got:

Blocked opening 'slack://open' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

If I try `vscode.open("slack://open");` I get

Property 'open' does not exist on type 'typeof import("vscode")'

Comment: Did you try the deep links? https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#client

Comment: create a `vscode.Uri` to the url you want and use `vscode.open` command

Comment: @LexLi deeplinking is indeed the way, but haven't been able to figure out how everything fits together, yet.